# Why enabling winmanager in VIM will close my current editting file?

Tags: vim

Why enabling winmanager in VIM will close my current editting file?

the following are my configuration file _vimrc

```
" Taglist (command: Tlist)
let Tlist_Show_One_File=1
let Tlist_Exit_OnlyWindow=1

" tags
set tags=E:\Source\code\tags

" WinManager
let g:winManagerWindowLayout='BufExplorer|TagList'    
map <c-w><c-m> :WMToggle<cr>
```

My computer is a PC, windows 10, and VIM version is 7.4 (GVIM)

I used GVIM to open a source code file, and input ":Tlist", the tag list window can be shown in VIM correctly, and work fine. My editting file is stall opened. everything is good. And I can use ":Tlist" again to close tag list window.

But as long as I use  to open winManager, the window containing my current editting source code file will be closed. the buf explorer window (on the top) and tag list window (at the bottom) will take all room in VIM. I tried to  h,i,j,k to nativate window, and failed to find my editting file window.

I don't know why and what's wrong.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my _vimrc file and found that as long as I comment the following code, the VIM could work fine with winManager. I am not sure it is the root cause, but it can resolve the problem.

```
" set windows 
set winwidth=360
set winminwidth=40
set winheight=720
```